# Is there any benefit of using the nameof operator instead of the CallerMemberNameAttribute to notify property changes in .NET 4.5.3?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, .net-4.6, callermembername, nameof

With the advent of .NET 4.5.3, WPF developers now have three (or more) ways to notify the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of property changes. Basically, my question is *Which of the two methods introduced from.NET 4.5 onwards is the more efficient way to notify property changes and whether either way has any benefit when being used in WPF?*

**Background**

For those not so familiar with this subject, here are the main three methods. The first is the original, more error prone method of simply passing a string:

```
public string TestValue
{
    get { return testValue; }
    set { testValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TestValue"); }
}

protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The second method was introduced in .NET 4.5; the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public string TestValue
{
    get { return testValue; }
    set { testValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The third and most recent method was (or will soon be) introduced in C#6.0 as part of .NET 4.5.3; the [`nameof` Operator](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570551):

```
public string TestValue
{
    get { return testValue; }
    set { testValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TestValue)); }
}

protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

My own assumption would be that the original, more error prone method of simply passing a string would be the most efficient, as I can only imagine that the other two methods use some form of reflection. However, I'm really keen to find out which of the other two methods is more efficient and whether there would actually be any difference between using the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` attribute and the `nameof` operator in a WPF context.

Comment: "The third and most recent method was (or will soon be) introduced in C#6.0 as part of .NET 4.5.3; the nameof Operator" - strictly speaking `nameof` is a [language feature](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) and not a part of framework.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

About efficiency: using a string directly, `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, `nameof` are all exactly the same since the string is injected by the compiler at compile-time. There's no reflection involved.

We can see that using TryRoslyn that [produces this for `CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlbxJroB0AwgPboAOFEqEyAshQCaoA2Oe0MhKGEgCVgjMOlTkq1MB1QAnOAoBuYAMaoQOasABGHdTDUcAhiBAwyMAN7Y+favLDKTaGCie80KAGomOwKg49jCOzq6oMACiygzIABImEKxy8gA8AAryFNQKyAhkABZJUKisMXEAgvJQIAB8MFk5eQXF0GXaegZq7siesAAqmsh+AajYtiGlyDYw8qjIwPIQMN4j/oGYMAC+dvYgC7Nro4EwALwwLmNbAHIUyGAAZghNufL5RSVlABQAlFu7XbYRz3VBqNCsS5gd7AfyXChgSF3B7PV4tT7tVjfADaZH8qSYGF0ChuJgkAF0PPhQtk3vlSRJzjAAETM34TPZ8J4wb5o96tL6QgCEFwgwA4HHZIUmIXsfI+bVKWOQhTAIAANDB6AB3Rq09GKsoVRjVWrfEF0hAM1C/f6cnbYXYhR1AA==):

```
public string TestValue
{
    get { return this.testValue; }
    set { this.testValue = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TestValue"); }
}
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And [this for `nameof`](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlbxJroB0AwgPboAOFEqEyAshQCaoA2Oe0MhKGEgCVgjMOlTkq1MB1QAnOAoBuYAMaoQOasABGHdTDUcAhiBAwyMAN7Y+favLDKTaGCie80KAGomOwKg49jCOzq6oMACiygzIABImEKxy8gA8AAryFNQKyAhkABZJUKisMXEAgvJQIAB8MFk5eQXF0GXaegZq7siesAAqmsh+AajYtiGlyDYw8qjIwPIQMN4j/oGYMAC+dvYgC7Nro4EwALwwLmNbAHIUyGAAZghNufL5RSVlABQQJhIUR7fIa+DaoACU4K2u122Ec91QajQrEuYHewH8lwoYBRdwez1eLU+7VY3w8+FC2Te+Ru/whEz2fEJ71aX1YAH4SABJCDKCgAa1Q32QhTAIAANDB6AB3RpUoltUrlWKMaq1b7w6kIWkSSE4XYhbDbIAAA==):

```
public string TestValue
{
    get { return this.testValue; }
    set { this.testValue = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TestValue"); }
}
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Since at runtime all options are simply a `string` there's no problem with the WPF context.

About convenience: `CallerMemberNameAttribute` requires you to have an optional parameter while `nameof` doesn't but `nameof` requires you to specify the property while `CallerMemberNameAttribute` doesn't.

I predict that `nameof` would turn out to be so popular that it would be much simpler to use it instead.

Comment: Why will nameof turn out to be so popular? It's a lot easier to use CallerMemberNameAttribute like once, or usually at least less than nameof (which you would have to use in every property). I don't understand these trends... Can you explain please?

Comment: @ElMac nameof has already turned out to be popular in many scenarios... not just to get the caller's name. More people know it and use it throughout so it's simpler to also use it here.

Answer (score 7):

The `CallerMemberNameAttribute` can only be used on the called function the get the name of the caller function.

The `nameof` operator goes way beyond that. It can be used anywhere.

If you want to reason about it just in the scope of WPF data binding, take this example:

```
public string FullName
{
   get
   {
       return string.Format(
           "{0} {1}",
           this.firstName,
           this.lastName);
   }
}

public string FirstName
{
   get
   {
       return this.firstName;
   }
   set
   {
       if (value != this.firstName)
       {
           this.firstName = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
           NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
   }
}

public string LasttName
{
   get
   {
       return this.lastName;
   }
   set
   {
       if (value != this.lastName)
       {
           this.lastName = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(LasttName));
           NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
   }
}
```